# Swift Json connection failed. JSON object correct?

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I've been having a lot of problems while trying to get a Json object into my iOS application. I created a Json file out of my MysqlDB like this:

```
<?php
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","FeedStuff") or die("Err$

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from articles";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . my$

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Now the json object seems to look good. plato.guru.ksz.ch/index.php would be the object. 
These are news articles that I load into my DB and they each have a ID, title, description, category, link, media and source, all of which are just strings ( except ID)

Now I try to get this Json file into my iOS object, to display each article in a table cell.
I run into problems but i'm not quite sure if it may be the Json file itself or the connection of my iOS app.

This is the swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let filePath = NSURL(string: "plato.guru.ksz.ch/index.php")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL:filePath!)
    let json = JSON(data: (jsonData)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)

    print(json)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

I imported the SwiftyJSON file manually because i wasn't able to get it working with the pods.
Now is my Json file incorrect or why am i receiving this error when i execute the programm:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Thanks for your help, been stuck with this for days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add http:// or https:// to your  string

```
let filePath = NSURL(string: "http://plato.guru.ksz.ch/index.php")
```

or

```
let filePath = NSURL(string: "https://plato.guru.ksz.ch/index.php")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Content-type` is `text/html`.  Set it to `application/json`

Use:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

In your php file

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly that does? My Json file doesn't change in context. I'm now struggling to parse it because in all tutorials that i've looked at before each object they declared a name such as: articles{"title":"Hello"}
or they even have the object within another array. 

Do I need to name each object or is there a way to parse it even without a specific name?

Comment: This tells clients that they can parse the result as JSON.  When I last hit your URL, it reported that it was HTML.  Clients are free to ignore the header and parse it anyway, but you should expect that some would report an error because they didn't think they got JSON.

Comment: Your JSON returns an array of objects, so you can do  `let a = json as? [AnyObject]` and that should give you the array.  Then you can do `let title = (a[0] as? [String:AnyObject])["title"] as? String` to get the title of the first article

Comment: it worked with the added header, now i can apply the regular JSON parsing that I've seen in other tutorials. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use **try** for assigning JSON data to variable **json**
There are plenty of tutorials on API connections, receiving JSON.

```
// Parse JSON
// By the way, is your variable JSON a dictionary?
// Here:

let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```